# Highlighting parent li when on a sub li

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an auto generated Wordpress menu that's created the following:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-23 page_item_has_children">
    <a href="#">Main item 1</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-52498 current_page_item">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-52496">
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-52477">
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**I want to say when I'm on the first sub item, highlight the main li.**

This is the CSS I'm using (ideally this would be more simple but due to the nature of the auto generated menu it's a bit messy!):

```
.page-item-52498.current_page_item li.page-item-23 a {
    color:white!important;
    font-family:'Museo Sans W01 500'!important;
}
```

At the moment this doesn't make the first `li a` white.

Comment: No possible with CSS alone, instead use `.page_item_has_children:hover {color: #f00;}` and set the color of active state, this way it will apply the color even when you move the cursor on the sub menu

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That CSS selector doesn't work. You cannot select the `.page-item-23` as a child of `.page-item-52498`, as it is a container for the other in the markup structure.

Have you tried outputting the page ID using the `body_class` function of WordPress? Then you could try using a selector such as `body.page-id-52498 li.page-item-23 a` or similar.

The `body_class` function is used as such (most probably in the `header.php` template file of WordPress):

```
<!-- <head> somewhere above -->
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!-- rest of the template somewhere below -->
```

It should output something similar to this (with a dynamic ID number of course):

```
<body class="page page-id-112 page-template logged-in admin-bar">
```

Whenever you've used `body_class` and it outputs the specific page ID you've declared in the CSS selector I wrote above it will take effect (following standard cascading rules of course).

Answer (score 0):

One for the future - the subject selector should be arriving in CSS4. It's going to be very powerful but easy to abuse I think.

Syntax

```
!subject > selector {
    /* declarations */
}
```

Example

```
!ul > li {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Scrolling down to the Parent Selector: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/

And http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/subject-of-selector-with-child-combinator/